# Use Of Cauchy Residue Theorem In Integrating Pure Trigonometric Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Saw this question:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^3t + \sin^2t dt$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos t\sin t)dt$$

Was told to solve using Cauchy Residue Theorem but I'm not sure how to go about it. Am I to convert it to a laurent series to get the residue? How do I go about it? I need help please

Comment: Do $z = e^{it}$.

Comment: $2\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos(t) dt = -i\int_{|z|=1} (1+\frac{1}{z^2}) dz$ can you prove why ?

Comment: Yes but how did you arrive at the integral $|z|=1$ ?

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I've figured it out